# MVC ActionResult parameter when Page refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ActionResult that uploads multiple files

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(object obj)
    {
        // Loading all files

        var result = new UploadResultProcess(fileUploads);
        UploadCache.CleanAdd(UploadCache.UploadResult, result);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { @loadAll =true});
    }
```

The `ActionResult` Details has optional parameter

```
   public ActionResult Details(bool loadAll=false)
   {
       // Load from cache
       var result = (UploadResultProcess)UploadCache.Get(UploadCache.UploadResult);
       result.Process(Uow, loadAll);
       return View(result);
    }
```

Based on `loadAll` parameter the function `result.Process` will process specific files only.

In my `Details` view when refresh is clicked, loadAll is still true, why is that? how can i rest the value to false if the refresh is clicked

Comment: How are you maintaining `loadAll` state in your View? Is there a hidden field for it and are you resetting hidden field value when you click refresh? Post your refresh button code or the action that is getting called on refresh click.

Comment: Your `RedirectToAction` is generating `.../Details/loadAll=true` so if you refresh the page, the the value of `loadAll` remains `true` (its in the url)

Comment: You are initialising `loadAll` to `true` in the `Action` Upload before you redirect to `Details` but you want it to it to be set to `false` in the `Action` Details. Why?

Comment: Because first time result.process is called, it perform very long process. so when the page is refreshed i would like to perform lighter process that's why i want to set loadAll to false. or maybe disable refresh if possible

Comment: No i don't have hidden field for that, is it possible to change the url parameter when refresh is clicked?